# Converting object keys

Tags: typescript

trying to convert keys

```
import { Url, parse } from "url";
export class HalJson {
    _links: Links;
}

export class HalLinks implements Links {
    toUrl( rel: string ): Url {
        let link = <Link> this[rel];
        return parse( link.href );
    }
    [text: string]: Link;
}

export interface Links {
    [text: string]: Link;
    toUrl( rel : string ) : Url;
}

export interface Link {
    href: string;
}
```

but I get this error

```
[default] C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui\src\util\Hal.ts:7:5 
    Property 'toUrl' of type '(rel: string) => Url' is not assignable to string index type 'Link'.
[default] C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui\src\util\Hal.ts:16:5 
    Property 'toUrl' of type '(rel: string) => Url' is not assignable to string index type 'Link'.
```

here's the instantiation code, which works (sans the `toUrl` code)

```
    client.fetch( '' ).then( response => {
        return response.json();
    } ).then( json => {
        let hal: HalJson = Object.assign( new HalJson(), json );
        hal._links = Object.assign( new HalLinks(), hal._links );
        log.debug( "json", hal );
```

I'm trying to figure out a way I can get a `Url` object back from my `application/hal+json` payload

(alternatively if anyone knows any typescript definitions libraries that would take hal json links and make it strictly typed, feel free to mention in the comments)

Comment: How are you creating an instance of `HalLinks`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer added, not that it'll be all that helpful

Comment: I don't think what you're doing is allowed. The indexer is the preferred match for *all* properties, so the compiler is trying to typecheck HalLinks#toUrl as just another string index. If you try adding a property to your interface that isn't of type `Link` (or a subtype), you'll get a compile error. Might be a compiler bug that this doesn't happen for methods.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains because an instance of `Links` can be used like this:

```
let a = links["toUrl"]("rel");
```

Then what is the type of `a`? Is it a `Link` or `Url`?
You can do:

```
interface Links {
    [text: string]: Link | Url;
    toUrl(rel: string): Url;
}

class HalLinks implements Links {
    toUrl(rel: string): Url {
        let link = <Link> this[rel];
        return parse(link.href);
    }
    [text: string]: Link | Url;
}
```

But then you'll need to cast everything that you retrieve from `HalLinks`:

```
let a1 = links["rel"] as Link;
let a2 = links["rel"] as Url; // no error, which isn't good.
```

I suggest something that requires more code but I think that it will be easier to work with:

```
interface Links {
    [text: string]: Link;
}

class HalLink {
    constructor(private link: Link) {}

    get href(): string {
        return this.link.href;
    }

    get url(): Url {
        return parse(this.link.href);
    }
}

class HalLinks {
    private links: { [rel: string]: HalLink };

    constructor(links: Links) {
        this.links = {};

        for (let key in links) {
            this.links[key] = new HalLink(links[key]);
        }
    }

    get(rel: string): HalLink {
        return this.links[rel];
    }

    url(rel: string): Url {
        return this.links[rel].url;
    }
}

let links: HalLinks;

let link1 = links.get("rel1");
let href1 = link1.href;
let url1 = link1.url;

let url2 = links.url("rel2");
```

Comment: not all that different from the alternative approach I came up with `export class HalJson {
    constructor( json: any ) {
        let hal: HalJson = Object.assign( this, json );
        hal._links = Object.assign( new HalLinks(), hal._links );
        Object.keys( hal._links ).forEach( key => {
            hal._links[ key ] = Object.assign( new HalLink(), hal._links[ key ] )
        } );
    }` and then puting the `toUrl` as a getter on the `Link`

Comment: It is very different. Which is why in my solution you are not faced with the error that your solution does.

Comment: what error would I experience in the solution in the comment?

Comment: How does the code in the comment changes the error for `Links`?

Comment: I don't have a `toUrl` in `Links` after that, I put that behavior in `Link`. It's an alternate way of avoiding the issue. Doesn't make your solution wrong, I just wanted to put that code somewhere in case someone else wanted it.

Comment: I can't really understand what we're even talking about. Update your question with your solution and then I'll be able to see